# Add custom text by onto each bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, annotations, geom-text

Can someone please help me put text onto each bar. I am using geomtext function but not sure how it works to put text on each bar Here is code:

```
df <- read.csv("F:/open_end_frequency_response.csv")
colnames(df)[1] = "modality"
colnames(df)[2] = "First_response"
colnames(df)[3] = "Second_response"
colnames(df)[4] = "Third_response"
colnames(df)[5] = "Fourth_response"
colnames(df)[6] = "Fifth_response"
dput(df)
colnames(df) <- c("modality","First_response","Second_response","Third_response",
                  "Fourth_response", "Fifth_response", "Frequency")

df2 <- select(df, -Frequency)
dat <- melt(df2)

#Using modality as id variables
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(modality, value, fill=interaction(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  ggtitle("A: General OEQ") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  scale_fill_brewer('Open-end', palette='RdPu') +  theme(legend.position = c(.51, .80)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Frequency") + theme(panel.border = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + 
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.0, "cm"), legend.key.width = unit(0.5,"cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.5,"cm")) + 
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = "a"), position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 2,
            vjust = -0.25, fontface="bold")
```

Please find below a piece of my data, I hope this will help you play with the data. Also I am not sure how to share data on stackoverflow, please if someone can share me the link:

```r
squads <- tibble::tribble(
                   ~test, ~first_res, ~second_res, ~third_res, ~fourth_res, ~fifth_res,
            "Appearance",       201L,         72L,        54L,         46L,        39L,
                 "Aroma",         8L,         17L,        17L,         24L,        13L,
                "Flavor",       107L,        148L,       177L,        168L,       122L,
               "Texture",       151L,        225L,       220L,        198L,       150L,
              "Abstract",       282L,        260L,       360L,        356L,       402L
            )
head(squads)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   test       first_res second_res third_res fourth_res fifth_res
#>   <chr>          <int>      <int>     <int>      <int>     <int>
#> 1 Appearance       201         72        54         46        39
#> 2 Aroma              8         17        17         24        13
#> 3 Flavor           107        148       177        168       122
#> 4 Texture          151        225       220        198       150
#> 5 Abstract         282        260       360        356       402
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example, as you need 25 texts, let `x <- c(1:25)`

add `geom_text(aes(label = x), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25)` like

```
ggplot(dat, aes(modality, value, fill=interaction(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  ggtitle("A: General OEQ") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  scale_fill_brewer('Open-end', palette='RdPu') +  theme(legend.position = c(.51, .80)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Frequency") + theme(panel.border = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + 
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.0, "cm"), legend.key.width = unit(0.5,"cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.5,"cm")) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = x), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25)
```

then result is like

[image: 1~25]

```
plot_grid(p1, p2, labels = c("p1", "p2"))
```

[image: add]

Sequence replaced

[image: abcd]

## Final code Edit (I guess)

In `dat <- melt(df2)`, add some code as `dat <- melt(df2) %>% arrange(modality)`. Then, for example `x <- c(1:25)`, `dat$text <- x`.
Now, code to plot is now

```
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(modality, value, fill=interaction(variable))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  ggtitle("A: General OEQ") + 
  theme_bw() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1, size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  scale_fill_brewer('Open-end', palette='RdPu') +  theme(legend.position = c(.51, .80)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  xlab("") + ylab("Frequency") + theme(panel.border = element_blank()) + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + 
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(1.0, "cm"), legend.key.width = unit(0.5,"cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.5,"cm")) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = text, group = ), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.25)
```

[image: sequence right]

Comment: Thanks @Park So are you suggesting me to specify x first and then use that x in the geom_text? How can I specify different text, `x <- c("a", "ab", "e", "cd")` , if this is how i should specify it.

Comment: @chetan You may specify text `x` as you said, which must have length of 25

Comment: Thanks @Park for the help. I got what I was trying to. Just one quick thing, I have 2 other similar plots and at the end I am combining all those by using `plot_grid` function so that all come up as a one figure. If you know why scripts/text i added is not showing on the final picture. Code snippet is here below: ```df2 <- select(df, -Frequency)
dat <- melt(df2)
x <- c("b", "bc", "a", "a", "a",
       "a", "b", "bc", "cd", "cde",
       "ab", "ab", "ab", "a", "b",
       "c", "ab", "a", "a", "bcd",
       "bc", "a", "a", "a", "b")
p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(modal```

Comment: @chetan Well...I get text in my plot...I'll add this plot above

Comment: Got it! Why my plots are not exactly following the position of the text, it seems they are automatically finding their position. Do I need something else here, like I want this `"b", "bc", "a", "a", "a", ` but what my graph is showing "a", "ab" one blank and then "a", "d". Any clue.

Comment: @chetan in `"b", "bc", "a", "a", "a", `, was there "ab" or "d"? Or them are just an example?

Comment: Yes, i have "ab" and "d" . Here is complete series `c("b", "bc", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "bc", "cd", "cde", "ab", "ab", "ab", "a", "b", "c", "ab", "a", "a", "bcd", "bc", "a", "a", "a", "b")`.

Comment: @chetan I'll take a look and reply. Thank you.

Comment: @chetan It seems they are safe and sound in my plot. I add it above

Comment: Yes, they are same but sequence is not same as I provided in the code. I want "b" on first bar, folllowed by "bc" and so on.

Comment: @chetan I can explain you that. As you can see in `p1` plot , sequence is `Appearance` -> `Aroma` - >... -> `Abstract` and from `First_response` -> .... -> `Fifth_response`. You might find order by numbers of `p1`. I'll try to find way to order sequence as you wanted.